# Layout is resizing after clicking on Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button, android-scrollview

I created a linear layout where i add horizontal scrollview and i added few buttons at run time on Horizontal scroll view. Initialy it looks fine but after clicking several button when i click on Categories button category container resizes as shown in images.

Please assist me why this is happening what is problem
Thanks.

Comment: paste some code here that will help us to resolve your problem in better mode

Comment: Is the height also shrinking? Is just the shifting of words the issue?

Comment: Can you please post the Layout's XML?

Comment: @fahad height is shrinking

Comment: open the xml in graphical view. Set the coupon and Categories in red selected form one by one. See which of them tends to reduce height. Overlapping text views or Fixed heigth of textView is the culprit here

Comment: MY BAD! I thought the value are not inflated on runTime?

Comment: @Fahad Ishaque this is not happening on clicking on perticular its happening when you click last remaining category

Comment: I told you try fixing the height for all the inner layout and apply wrap content on the parent layout.

Answer (score -1):

Here is layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/root_view_deals_screen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout_category_panel_main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/color_category_panel_bg"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_previous"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView_category_panel"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ImageView_next"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView_previous"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="15dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/Layout_category_panel_container"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView_next"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</RelativeLayout>

<com.techdeals.rest.ui.widget.IndexableListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RelativeLayout_category_panel_main"
    android:divider="@drawable/list_divider"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ImageView_list_divider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/list_divider" />
```

Comment: everything in the relativeLayout-> set its heigth to 25dp. Then your set to go.

Comment: @FahadIshaque thanks for your answer but text on button is coming from bottom

Comment: Fix its height also. Your height parameters ->wrap content are contradicting thats why this issue is happeneing

Answer (score -1):

```
Here is Button.xml file which i am inflating at runtime .

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Button_category_panel"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:textSize="16dp"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```